# passwd command complains about user not existing

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat usernames.txt)

do
    echo $i
    useradd $i -m -s /bin/bash $i -G groupy $i
    passwd=echo "password" | passwd $i
    passwd -e $i
    echo "User must change password when they come back"

done
```

What it is supposed to be doing is:

- Creating users by the names given in the file with a home directory
- Their password would be default "password" and they must change it the next time they login
- Putting them into a group called "groupy" that has already been created

This is just practice for a class where the majority of the time we just read chapters. Our teacher wants us to attempt this but the chapter we read has nothing to do with this kind of script building. I really am unsure as to what I am doing wrong. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and/or point me in the right direction?

I continue to get this as output:

```
passwd: user 'wworthington' does not exist
./myscript: line 8: password: command not found
passwd: Permission denied.
User must change password when they come back
```

Comment: @eclark Well, the whole script need to be run with root privileges, since the only user allowed to set a new password for another user than himself is root.

Comment: What this command `passwd=echo "password" | passwd $i` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your most immediate problem is with permissions. User 'wworthington' was not created, which means that `useradd` did not work. Most systems require you to run as a super-user, either by logging in as `root` or using the `sudo` command to run administrative commands like `useradd` and `passwd` (see [intro to sudo](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo) for more info). `passwd` can be run by a normal user for his/her own account or by the super-user for any user account (see [passwd man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html)).

Also, `passwd=echo "password" | passwd $i` sets a variable called `passwd` to `echo` and then runs a non-existent command `"password"` piping the (empty) output to `passwd $i`. You can set user `$i`'s password to "password" and set the expiration date in your `useradd` command with the`-p` and `-e` options, respectively (see [useradd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)). Both options require a value after the option tag (like you did with `-G groupy` and `-s /bin/bash`).

Comment: Now it runs through the usernames but for every user name it says:
username
'seradd: invalid user name 'username
passwd: Permission denied.
User must change password when they come back

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@bogon test]# useradd --help
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
   useradd -D
   useradd -D [options]

Options:
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the
                            new account
  -c, --comment COMMENT         GECOS field of the new account
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory of the new account
  -D, --defaults                print or change default useradd     
configuration
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  expiration date of the new account
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       password inactivity period of the new      
 account
  -g, --gid GROUP               name or ID of the primary group of the new
                            account
  -G, --groups GROUPS           list of supplementary groups of the new
                            account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --skel SKEL_DIR           use this alternative skeleton directory
  -K, --key KEY=VALUE           override /etc/login.defs defaults
  -l, --no-log-init             do not add the user to the lastlog and
                            faillog databases
  -m, --create-home             create the user's home directory
  -M, --no-create-home          do not create the user's home directory
  -N, --no-user-group           do not create a group with the same name as
                            the user
  -o, --non-unique              allow to create users with duplicate
                            (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account
  -r, --system                  create a system account
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -s, --shell SHELL             login shell of the new account
  -u, --uid UID                 user ID of the new account
  -U, --user-group              create a group with the same name as the user
```

## -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     use a specific SEUSER for the SELinux user mapping

your useradd has too many param, just simply:
useradd  -m -s /bin/bash  -G groupy $i

passwd=echo "password" | passwd $i
are you want to pass 'password' to passwd?
the right way is : `echo "password" | passwd --stdin $i`

finally,the working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

for i in $(cat usernames.txt)

do
    echo "useradd  -m -s /bin/bash  -G groupy $i"
    useradd  -m -s /bin/bash  -G groupy $i
    echo "password" |  passwd --stdin $i 
    passwd -e $i
    echo "User must change password when they come back"

done